# jQuery add z-index value to a series of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery, z-index

Simple concept, but I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant solution.

I've got a series of images in a gallery and the amount inside will change. I've written a short script that runs through a slideshow, fading the visible image out with the next underneath it. Conceptually it's perfect, but above 2 images it gets wonky because the "next" images are all on the same z-index.

Is there a simple script that can count the photos and add a progressive z-index to them? For example: there are 10 images in the gallery and it assigns them z-indexes -1 through -10.

Thanks for your help!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/mmPZN/

HTML:

```
<img class="slide first" src="img/diamond-test.jpg" />
<img class="slide" src="img/diamond-test2.jpg" />
<img class="slide" src="img/diamond-test3.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
  top:100px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.first {
  display:block;
  position:static;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.slide').click(function(){
    var pic = $(this);
    pic.fadeOut(400, function(){
        pic.next().addClass('first');
        pic.insertAfter('.slide:last').removeClass('first').show();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solid fix, didn't need to z-index all the images sequentially.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/mmPZN/1/

JavaScript:

```
$('.slide:first').addClass('first').next().addClass('second');
$('.slide').click(function(){
    var pic = $(this);
    pic.fadeOut(400, function(){
    pic.next().removeClass('second').addClass('first').next().addClass('second');
        pic.insertAfter('.slide:last').removeClass('first').show();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to stack all the images. You just need a container and an image. The first image is a background, then one image is on top of it. Fade in the image on top, then make it the background. Hide the image, swap the SRC to the next image. Fade-in and repeat.

The example demonstrates the technique. Yours will work a little differently because you have multiple images. Same idea though.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

Comment: Good suggestion, but this will eventually be used with a CMS and I can't hardcode the hover source or assume that the person using it won't be an idiot. I'll see if I can figure out some way to always code the top, next, and rest into line.

Comment: You can use a hidden DIV to hold the images, then use a bit of JavaScript to pull out the SRC values into an array, feed it into the image swapper and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

why not just set the visibility to hide on all except the one you want to look at? z-index doesnt always work well in certain browsers

Comment: I could fade one image out then fade another in, but I'm specifically going for the melt into the next one effect. Because of that, the second image in the series needs to be visible underneath the first